# How to split a string within a list to create key-value pairs in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a list that looks like this:

```
[ 'abc=lalalla', 'appa=kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka=oeoeoeo']
```

And I want to split this list by '=' so that everything on the left side will become keys and on the right, values.

```
{ 
    'abc':'lalalla',
    'appa':'kdkdkdkd',
    'kkakaka':'oeoeo'
}
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
a = [ 'abc=lalalla', 'appa=kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka=oeoeoeo']
d = dict(s.split('=') for s in a)
print d


Output:
{'kkakaka': 'oeoeoeo', 'abc': 'lalalla', 'appa': 'kdkdkdkd'}
```

http://codepad.org/bZ8lGuHE

Answer (score 15):

In addition, make sure you limit the splits to 1, in case the right-hand side contains an '='.

```
d = dict(s.split('=',1) for s in a)
```

Answer (score 7):

```
print dict([s.split("=") for s in my_list])
```

like this

```
>>> my_list = [ 'abc=lalalla', 'appa=kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka=oeoeoeo']
>>> print dict(s.split("=") for s in my_list) #thanks gribbler
{'kkakaka': 'oeoeoeo', 'abc': 'lalalla', 'appa': 'kdkdkdkd'}
```

Comment: Unless your python is very old, you can leave the list comprehension out and use a generator expression as Demian does

Comment: thanks gribbler :) I use 2.6 and always forget I can do that .. mostly because i cant do dict comprehensions

Answer (score 2):

You can feed a `map` object directly to `dict`. For built-in functions without arguments, `map` should show similar or better performance. You will see a drop-off in performance when introducing arguments:

```
from functools import partial

L = ['abc=lalalla', 'appa=kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka=oeoeoeo']
L2 = ['abc lalalla', 'appa kdkdkdkd', 'kkakaka oeoeoeo']

n = 100000
L = L*n
L2 = L2*n

%timeit dict(map(partial(str.split, sep='='), L))  # 234 ms per loop
%timeit dict(s.split('=') for s in L)              # 164 ms per loop

%timeit dict(map(str.split, L2))                   # 141 ms per loop
%timeit dict(s.split() for s in L2)                # 144 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Example by using [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function

```
a = ["abc=lalalla", "appa=kdkdkdkd", "kkakaka=oeoeoeo"]
d = dict(map(lambda s: s.split('='), a))
```