# How to create a dictionary from a list with a list of keys only and key-value pairs (Python)?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

This is an extension of this question: [How to split a string within a list to create key-value pairs in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739911/how-to-separate-string-and-create-a-key-value-pairs-python)

The difference from the above question is the items in my list are not all key-value pairs; some items need to be assigned a value.

I have a list:

```
list = ['abc=ddd', 'ef', 'ghj', 'jkl=yui', 'rty']
```

I would like to create a dictionary:

```
dict = { 'abc':'ddd', 'ef':1, 'ghj':1, 'jkl':'yui', 'rty':1 }
```

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
a = {}
for item in list:
   if '=' in item: 
     d = item.split('=')
     a.append(d) #I don't I can do this.
   else:
     a[item] = 1 #feel like I'm missing something here.
```

Comment: Please include the code you tried and the problems with it.

Comment: you need some parser logic, which detects list elements containing '=' and splits those into key and value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For each split "pair", you can append `[1]` and extract the first 2 elements. This way, 1 will be used when there isn't a value:

```
print dict((s.split('=')+[1])[:2] for s in l)
```

Comment: This is a stunner. Brilliant!

Comment: thanks @fabricator! Could explain why it doesn't work if you don't specifically extract the first two elements `[:2]`? Want to make sure I understand everything.

Comment: @AmeliaNChu, just because `dict` method requires it. from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict): `Otherwise, the positional argument must be an iterable object. Each item in the iterable must itself be an iterable with exactly two objects`

Comment: Note, will fail silently if there are ever two or more "=" in s. (It'll truncate at the second "=").

Answer (score 5):

I would be using something similar to the post you linked.

```
d = dict(s.split('=') for s in a)
```

If you combine what you can learn from this post -- that is to use lists to create dictionaries -- and from using [if/else in Python's list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-pythons-list-comprehension), you can come up with something like this:

```
d = dict(s.split("=", maxsplit=1) if "=" in s else [s, 1] for s in l)
```

What this does is add `1` to the end of the split list if there is no equal sign in it.

Comment: `[s]+[1]` can be shorten into `[s, 1]`

Comment: This is the real stunner in my books - one line *and* completely readable.

Comment: Note, will crash (raise ValueError) if there are ever two or more "=" in `s`. Which may well be the best thing to do.

Comment: If you want to crash-proof it use `s.split("=", maxsplit=1)`. I had to look that up. But as soon as I thought of the need, I suspected that the split method must have provided for it, and it had. Which is why I love Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
input_list = ['abc=ddd', 'ef', 'ghj', 'jkl=yui', 'rty']
output_dict = {}

for item in input_list:
    item_split = item.split('=')
    key = item_split[0]
    value = item_split[1] if len(item_split)>1 else 1
    output_dict[key] = value
```

a bit more concisely

```
for item in input_list:
    i_s = item.split('=')
    output_dict[i_s[0]] = i_s[1] if len(i_s)>1 else 1
```

This has the advantage that it doesn't append an extra element to each list created by splitting the elements of the input_list. Though, list comprehensions can be faster than a `for` loop

Comment: It can be done much more easily, but I would wait for the code tried and errors faced first before I post it.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the step-by-step approach.

```
In [50]: mylist = ['abc=ddd', 'ef', 'ghj', 'jkl=yui', 'rty']

In [51]: [element.split('=') for element in mylist]
Out[51]: [['abc', 'ddd'], ['ef'], ['ghj'], ['jkl', 'yui'], ['rty']]

In [52]: [element.split('=') + [1] for element in mylist]
Out[52]: [['abc', 'ddd', 1], ['ef', 1], ['ghj', 1], ['jkl', 'yui', 1], ['rty', 1]]

In [53]: [(element.split('=') + [1])[:2] for element in mylist]
Out[53]: [['abc', 'ddd'], ['ef', 1], ['ghj', 1], ['jkl', 'yui'], ['rty', 1]]

In [54]: dict((element.split('=') + [1])[:2] for element in mylist)
Out[54]: {'abc': 'ddd', 'ef': 1, 'ghj': 1, 'jkl': 'yui', 'rty': 1}
```

- In order to convert your list in line 50 to a dictionary, you will need to convert it to the list in line 53.
- Line 51. The first step is to split each element in the list by the equal sign. Each element now is transformed into a list of 1- or 2 elements. Notice that some element like `'ef'` which does not have equal sign, we will have to fix that
- Line 52. Next, we append 1 to each sub list. That should take care of the sublists with 1 element, but making some sublist 3 element long
- Line 53: We normalize all sublist into 2-element ones by taking just the first two element and discard the third one if applicable. This list now is in the correct format to convert into a dictionary
- Line 54. The last step is to take this list and convert it into a dictionary. Since the `dict` class can take a generator expression, we can safely remove the square brackets.

With that, here is the snippet:

```
mylist = ['abc=ddd', 'ef', 'ghj', 'jkl=yui', 'rty']
mydict = dict((element.split('=') + [1])[:2] for element in mylist)
```